# Can nodes be made to automatically restart on segmentation faults?

Tags: roslaunch

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is there a convenient way to tell roslaunch to automatically restart nodes if/when they segfault or otherwise die.

I realize that in an ideal world, I'd just fix the errors properly. However, parts of the code aren't mine and I'll be using them in a live demo. So I'd prefer to have them run in a 'best effort' mode. :)

One obvious option would be to launch the buggy nodes using a bash script:

```
while : ; do rosrun package node; done
```

but I was wondering if there was a more idiomatic ROS style?

Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/38808/can-nodes-be-made-to-automatically-restart-on-segmentation-faults?/) by [Benjamin Johnston](https://answers.ros.org/users/1983/benjamin-johnston/) on ROS Answers with karma: 50 on 2012-07-15

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

roslaunch provides the `respawn` attribute. E.g.:

```
<roslaunch>
  <node name="foo" pkg="package" type="node" respawn="true" />
</roslaunch>
```

Check out the documentation [here](http://ros.org/wiki/roslaunch/XML/node).

---

Originally posted by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) with karma: 22731 on 2012-07-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tlinder](https://answers.ros.org/users/2680/tlinder/) on 2012-07-15**:
Yes respawn will to the job. But may the questioner shut more be concerned about the segmentation fault and its causes, rather then just search for a work around. By the way, the most common cause of segfault is bad memory handling and faulty assumptions about availability of resources.

**Comment by [Benjamin Johnston](https://answers.ros.org/users/1983/benjamin-johnston/) on 2012-07-15**:
Thanks Lorenz.. that's exactly what I was looking for. I feel a bit silly now for not having noticed it in the documentation.